# Повелительное наклонение: расстягивай молнию на куртке или расстегай?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, наклонение-глагола

Как правильно: расстягивай молнию на куртке или расстегай?

Comment: Ресстегай - это пирожок. А "молнию" (кстати, она пишется в кавычках) - РАССТЕГИВАЮТ.))))

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: *(не) ра**с**тягивай молнию на куртке* (в смысле не увеличивай размер в длину), *(не) ра**сс**тёгивая молнии на куртке* (не открывая). "Не расстегая молнии" - это совсем просторечный вариант.